# How to design the class when there is more common operations?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following classes, representing webpages

```
App
Header
TableOperations
```

`Header` is common for all pages. So I can write:

```
class App extends Header
```

`TableOperations` class represent the operations that are related to table. All webpage has a table too, which has common operation. Now how do I design these 3 classes?

Now how `App` can use both classes methods?

I can't extend two classes in java. 
Any other way?

Comment: You can't `extend` two classes, *but* you can `implement` two.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using inheritance which should be used for objects with an `is a` relationship I would recommend composition.  If you continue with the inheritance strategy you are likely to build a large class hierarchy where each class extends the other, which is not preferred.

```
class App{
    Header header = new Header();
    TableOperations operations = new TableOperations();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I use like this, then I need to create methods for table operations, right? Lets say I have method called `A` in `TableOperations`, then in `App` class, I need to have method `routeToA` which again invoke `TableOperations` `A` method, Right?

Comment: Yes or you could expose the table operations via a getter, such as `app.getTableOperations().a();`

Answer (score 3):

[Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) is your friend here. I would perhaps have your classes implement their specific interfaces. You can then use multiple *interface* inheritance in order to specify that `App` will implement functionality from your other 2 interfaces.

e.g.

```
class Header implements IHeader
class TableOperations implements ITableOperations

class App implements IHeader, ITableOperations {
   private final IHeader header = new Header();

   // method declared in IHeader
   public void methodForHeader() {
      header.methodForHeader();
   }
}
```

`App` would then delegate appropriately to the underlying implementations `Header` and `TableOperations` (most likely implemented as members)

etc...

Comment: I need to create instance variables for `Header` in `App` class, and call the header methods in the interface implementaion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Header` use `is-a` i.e. part of structure and has common state for all hierarchy. And for `operations` `has-a` structure because the name `operations` says he has only operations, not `state`. But of course it depends your structure and requirements.

```
class App extends Header {
    TableOperations ops = new TableOperations();
}
```